# Call ordinary filter function in AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

In my view I use a function to filter some items in a selection box:

```
<select class="..."
  ng-model="selectedItem"
  ng-options="item.name for item in items | filter:filterItems(someArgument)">
</select>
```

This function is defined as an ordinary function in the controller, it is not an AngularJS filter:

```
$scope.filterItems = function(someArgument) {
  return function(item) {
    // Do something

    return someResult;
  }
};
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now, however, I want to use the same filter function in the controller and count the number of items after filtering.

I CANNOT use this code, since `filterItems()` is not an AngularJS filter:

```
$scope.countFilteredItems = function() {
  return $filter('filterItems')($scope.items, someArgument).length;
};
```

Is there any way I can use my filter function in the controller, without actually re-implementing the entire filtering process myself? Can I use the `$filter` service with my vanilla filter function?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)? You can pass an arbitrary predicate function to `$filter`.

Comment: Like this: ``$filter('filter')($scope.items, $scope.filterItems(someArgument))``?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to call my filter function with the `$filter` service, as @jonrsharpe suggested in his comment:

```
$scope.countFilteredItems = function() {
  var filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, $filterItems(someArgument));

  var count = 0;
  if (filteredItems !== undefined && filteredItems !== null) {
    count = filteredItems.length;
  }

  return count;
};
```